# Set Lexer rule from value in input stream

Tags: antlr4

I have this simple grammar file:

```
expr         : ID Divider ID;
divider_stat : 'Divider' Divider;

Divider : '#';

ID      : ALPHA ('_' | ALPHA | DIGIT)*;

fragment ALPHA  : [a-zA-Z];
fragment DIGIT  : [0-9];

SkipTokens  : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

In this case, `Divider` is fixed (`#`). But in real scenario, `Divider` will be defined as the char after `'Divider'` keyword.

Is there anyway to set `Divider` according to the value in `divider_stat`?

For input:

```
Divider -
id1 - id2
```

Tokens will be:

```
<ID>,'id1'
<Divider>,'-'
<ID>,'id2'
```

For input:

```
Divider $
id1$id2
```

Tokens will be:

```
<ID>,'id1'
<Divider>,'$'
<ID>,'id2'
```

The divider is always 1 char

Comment: Is the divider always 1 char?

Comment: yes, divider is always 1 char

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [lexical mode](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/lexer-rules.md#lexical-modes) for this, a bit of target specific code and a [predicate](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/predicates.md). Whenever the lexer "sees" the keyword `"Divider"`, it moves in the `DividerMode` where only a space can be matched (and is skipped) or a non-space is matched, which will become the new divider char. Inside the `Divider` lexer rule, you first chck (with a predicate) if the next character in the stream is the current divider-char.

Here's a small Java demo:

#### `DemoLexer.g4`

```
lexer grammar DemoLexer;

@members {
  private char divider = '#';
}

K_Divider : 'Divider' -> skip, pushMode(DividerMode);
Divider   : {_input.LA(1) == divider}? . ;
ID        : ALPHA ('_' | ALPHA | DIGIT)*;

fragment ALPHA  : [a-zA-Z];
fragment DIGIT  : [0-9];

SkipTokens  : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;

mode DividerMode;
 Spaces     : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
 NewDivider : ~[ \t\r\n] {this.divider = getText().charAt(0);} -> skip, popMode;
```

#### `DemoParser.g4`

```
parser grammar DemoParser;

options {
  tokenVocab=DemoLexer;
}

parse : expr+ EOF;
expr  : ID Divider ID;
```

And a small Java class to test it all:

```java
String source =
    "id1 # id2\n" +
    "Divider -\n" +
    "id3 - id4";

DemoLexer lexer = new DemoLexer(CharStreams.fromString(source));
DemoParser parser = new DemoParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
ParseTree root = parser.parse();

System.out.println(root.toStringTree(parser));
```

will print:

```
(parse (expr id1 # id2) (expr id3 - id4) <EOF>)
```

When using lexical modes, you need to separate the lexer- and parser grammar files. You could also use a combined grammar, but then you'd need to match `Divider ?` in one go:

#### `Demo.g4`

```
grammar Demo;

@lexer::members {
  private char divider = '#';
}

parse : expr+ EOF;
expr  : ID Divider ID;

K_Divider : 'Divider' [ \t\r\n]+ ~[ \t\r\n] {this.divider = getText().charAt(getText().length() - 1);} -> skip;
Divider   : {_input.LA(1) == divider}? . ;
ID        : ALPHA ('_' | ALPHA | DIGIT)*;

fragment ALPHA  : [a-zA-Z];
fragment DIGIT  : [0-9];

SkipTokens  : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```